Does "via in a pad" (not via-in-pad) cost extra?
I am trying to add vias to test point pads (40mil round copper pads) on the top layer.  I know via-in-pad costs extra due to extra manufacturing steps to fill the vias.  But if I add a via in a test point pad, will it cost extra?  I assume it's similar to adding a via to a copper trace.  Thanks.

No, as far as I'm aware for a normal via (I've never been charged for via in pad and I've done many many PCB designs and many different manufactuers)
Also there isn't an additional process with via in pad that costs the manufacturer more, so they won't pass that on to you.
If you have a filled via in pad, then it will follow the same cost schedule for filled vias. If you have to have copper over the via, then it will probably cost extra.
